# PIG using HCatLoader, Java heap space error

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hcatalog

I am using `hive-0.12.0,pig-0.12.0,mysql-5.6` and `hadoop-1.2.1` in pseudo distribution mode.

I configured `PIG_CLASSPATH` etc.. details according to the link,
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HCatalog+LoadStore

When I try to load a table created in hive into **pig** using **HCatloader**, it is giving the Java heap space error.

**The details are as follows:**

> hive.metastore - Trying to connect to metastore with URI
>   thrift://127.0.0.1:3306 2014-04-11 01:12:36,432 [main] INFO 
>   hive.metastore - Waiting 1 seconds before next connection attempt.
>   2014-04-11 01:12:37,432 [main] INFO  hive.metastore - Connected to
>   metastore. 2014-04-11 01:12:37,785 [main] ERROR
>   org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal
>   error. Java heap space Details at logfile:
>   /home/aphadoop/pig_1397158893348.log

Has anybody encountered the same error and solved it?

Please let me know.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Refer the link below to get some idea about the problem.
http://www.thecloudavenue.com/2013/11/InstallingAndConfiguringHCatalogAndIntegratingWithPig.html

Comment: Please give some info before linking it to the website. This helps in few click to get a birds eye view of the solution.